# Keeping removed value with Preg_Replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using preg_replace to remove some content from a string. What I am wondering is if there is a way to keep the stuff that is removed in a different variable. Here is what I am using:

```
$city = preg_replace('/^([0-9]* \w+ )?(.*)$/', '$2', $content[2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a preg_match() first to get the content which will be replaced, and then replace the content as you do.

Answer (score 3):

First get all the matches in your string with preg_match_all() and then run preg_replace() to do the actual replacing.

Comment: Once you have the matches, you shouldn't really need `preg_replace()` anymore and could use `str_replace()`. After all, there's no need to match anymore :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and assign the matches to variables before you replace them in your callback:

```
$pattern = '/^([0-9]* \w+ )?(.*)$/';
$matches = array();
$replace = function($groups) use (&$matches)
{
    $matches = $groups;
    return $groups[2];
};
$city = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $content[2]);

var_dump($city, $matches);
```

However in your specific case, you don't even need to run `preg_replace` at all, you can just use `preg_match`:

```
$pattern = '/^([0-9]* \w+ )?(.*)$/';
$subject= $content[2];
$r = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);    
list($replaced,,$city) = $matches; # the result you're looking for.
```